# Legend in Multi line chart - d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While adding a legend to my multi line graph my result is:
[image]

The passed ,failed etc... are half visible.
code:

```
   var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 1090 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 339 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

   var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

  var line = d3.svg.line()  
.interpolate("linear")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.days); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.testRuns); });

 var svg = d3.select("#application_status_graph").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + '0%')
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 d3.json("js/lineChartData.json", function(error, data) {
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {return key !== "days"; }));
   data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.days = parseInt(d.days);
   });

   var status = color.domain().map(function(name){
return{
    name: name,
    values: data.map(function(d){
        return {days: d.days, testRuns: +d[name]};
    }) 
}
   });
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.days; }));

y.domain([0, d3.max(status, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {           return v.testRuns; }); })]);
   svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

   svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Number of Test Runs");

var legend = svg.selectAll('.city')
    .data(status)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend');

legend.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

legend.append('rect')
    .attr('x', width - 20)
    .attr('y', function(d, i){ return i *  20;})
    .attr('width', 10)
    .attr('height', 10)
    .style('fill', function(d) { 
      return color(d.name);
    });

legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', width - 8)
    .attr('y', function(d, i){ return (i *  20) + 9;})
    .text(function(d){ return d.name; });

 });
```

I have played around the width all around the code. But i couldn't acheive the following:

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to do two things. First, restrict the x range of the graph itself so it doesn't extend too far. The easiest way to do this is by adjusting the `range` of your `x` scale:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([0, width-20]);
```

Second, you need to adjust the coordinates of the legend:

```
legend.append('rect').attr('x', width - 30)
```

and similarly for the other elements. On a general note, you may prefer moving the entire legend group instead of each element individually, i.e. you would move the group like so:

```
var legend = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 30) + ",20)")
                .selectAll('.city')
                .data(status)
                ...
```

Then the coordinates of the legend elements are local to this group and moving the entire legend only requires adjusting the coordinates of the `g` element.