# d3 legend (text + line representation)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am a newbie to d3js and I am currently plotting some multiple line chart graphs. One thing I want to do is to add a legend for each line. I figured out that I can add some text and I can also give the text some color, which is same as the line's color. However, I would like to add some line representation in front of the text. For example,
[Legend in Multi line chart - d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488385/legend-in-multi-line-chart-d3)
as we can see here, the legend starts with a colored rectangle + text, and I want it a line (dashed line for example) rather than rectangle in front of the text.

Is there anyone can help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The easiest way for you is just copy the approach with the rectangles in the legend and set the height to 1 (or 2), then you have a line.

Comment: Yes, that is one way, thanks for that, but how can I make it a dashed line?

Comment: Then it might be better to use a short line element and set the stroke-dasharray property accordingly.

Comment: you mean use another "path"?

Comment: No, just an [SVG line](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_line.asp) element.